# Convert unicode cyrillic symbols to string in python 2.7

Tags: python

**code:**

```py
    # coding: utf_8
    from __future__ import print_function
    print(u"Программа салфеток".encode("utf-8"))
```

**result:**
    ╨ƒ╤Ç╨╛╨│╤Ç╨░╨╝╨╝╨░ ╤ü╨░╨╗╤ä╨╡╤é╨╛╨║

Comment: `print(u"Программа салфеток".encode("utf-8")) .  Программа салфеток` . works fine in 2.7.15.  what is the problem?

Comment: @ShpielMeister my version: Python 2.7.17

Comment: @ShpielMeister my python doesn't understand cyrillic

Comment: try the following as the first or second line or your program (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations):    `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @ShpielMeister result: ╨ƒ╤Ç╨╛╨│╤Ç╨░╨╝╨╝╨░ ╤ü╨░╨╗╤ä╨╡╤é╨╛╨║

Comment: try `export LC_ALL='C'` . before you run python.